# How to include these exception handle symbols in x86 assembly code?

Tags: disassembly, x86, c++, reassembly, exception

The test is on 32bit x86 Linux, with `g++` 4.6.3.

So basically I use a [IDA pro script](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-recover-the-exception-info-from-gcc-except-table-and-eh-handle-sections) to recover the `.gcc_excpt_table` and `.eh_frame` sections from binary compiled from `C++` language.

Basically I want to reuse the dumped information of these two exception handling tables in a new assembly code disassembled from this `C++` ELF binary.

I put these two tables into the assembly code produced by disassembler, solving all intra-module address issue (basically translate concrete addresses into symbols) and re-compile it like this:

```
g++ final.s
```

However, there are three symbols that can not be found or I just don't know how to define it.

1. `_Unwind_Resume` are undefined
2. `__FRAME_END__` are undefined
3. It seems that `eh_frame` requires the beginning address of `.plt` table, but is there anyway to get the beginning address of `.plt` table during compiling? I know I can use the symbol `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` to represent the beginning address of table `.got.plt`, but after a quick search, I just don't know whether there is a similar symbol representing `.plt` table.